# What's the best way to do a just-in-time import of Python libraries?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a Python program that has several slow imports.  I'd like to delay importing them until they are needed.  For instance, if a user is just trying to print a help message, it is silly to import the slow modules. What's the most Pythonic way to do this?

I'll add a solution I was playing with as a answer. I know you all can do better, though.

Comment: If all you want to do is provide a quicker startup in certain situations then separate your code into logical modules. That is, the entry module analyses what needs to be done (print help, run main program, some auxiliary function) and then only loads the main module when it knows it needs to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just import them where they're needed. After a module has been imported once, it is cached so that any subsequent imports will be quick. If you import the same module 20 times, only the first one will be slow.

Comment: True but the only problem is that doing so is against the coding guidelines defined in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) where it says "Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants".

Comment: @martineau, PEP 8 also says "know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply." This is one of those cases, because if you follow the guideline it becomes impossible to do lazy loading.

Comment: I totally agree and brought the point up mostly as a straw-horse.

Comment: This is basically what I am already doing, I was just worried about making the code readable. I'll go with this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'sys' as an example module, the following code could work

```
class Importsys(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        global sys
        import sys
        setattr(sys, name, value)
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        global sys
        import sys
        return getattr(sys, name)
sys = Importsys()
```

This would ensure that when I try to use the sys module, it is automagically imported, and replaces the sys module variable.  However, I would have to create separate classes for each module for which I want Just-In-Time importing.  I suppose I could use the __import__('sys') function, but that seems to create a recursion issue.

Comment: This was an overly complex idea. Do what Mark suggested in the other answer. Leaving it up here to show I've learning something in a decade?